# How to know which app is getting used in background in your react native app?

Tags: react-native, background-process

I wanted to build an app which can send notifications to the user if he uses a particular app for more than 15 minutes...for this I need to trace which app the user is using even when my react native app is not being used(i.e. it is present in the background). Is there any react native library which can help me to know the app which the user is using in the present?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. Your app would have to be running in the background at all times, and even then the OS would have to support such a feature.

Comment: If that is so then how are app blockers built? Can I build something like this if I learn kotlin or java...cause building this app is really important to me..

Comment: @Pro You mean ad blockers? Can you give us an example about what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This type of app will surely get denied when submitted for privacy reasons, this definitely is not allowed

Comment: @AidanHakimian [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.mobilesoft.appblock&hl=en_US&gl=US) is what I am talking about..